# Portable reinterpretation of uint8_t as int8_t and forcing two's complement

Tags: c, casting, stdint

I am trying to reinterpret a uint8_t as an int8_t (and back again) in a way that is portable. I'm as I am receiving over a serial channel that I store in a buffer of uint8_t, but once I know what kind of packet it is, I need to interpret some of the bytes as two's compliment and others as unsigned.

I know that this will work on many compilers:

```
int8_t i8;
uint8_t u8 = 0x94;

i8 = (int8_t)u8;
```

But it is not guaranteed to work when u8>127 because casting a value greater than INT8_MAX to int8_t is undefined (I think).

The best I have been able to come up with is this

```
int8_t i8;
uint8_t u8;

i8 = (u8 > INT8_MAX) ? (int8_t)(-(256-u8)):(int8_t)u8;
```

This should always work because subtraction always will cause an automatic promotion to at int, and in no way relies on the underlying representations. It implicitly forces a two's complement interpretation of values greater than INT8_MAX.

Is there a better way (or a standard MACRO) to do this?

Comment: I was going to put forward type-punning with a `signed char`: `i8 = (int8_t)*(signed char *)&u8;`, but that may not work on a hypothetical platform that does not use two's complement for its negative integer type representations.

Answer (score 8):

If `int8_t` is defined (by `<stdint.h>`), it is guaranteed to be two’s complement (by C 2018 7.20.1.1).

The value in `uint8_t u8` can be reinterpreted as a two’s complement value by copying it to `int8_t i8` with `memcpy(&i8, &u8, sizeof i8);`. (Good compilers will optimize this to simply use the `u8` as a two’s complement value, with no call to `memcpy`.)

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad to learn that int8_t as defined by stdint.h is guaranteed two's compliment! Can I assume that this holds for all of the intN_t types (perhaps not fast or least)?

Comment: @Chris: Yup, [cppreference says 2's complement for all `int##_t` types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) (no guarantees for `fast`/`least`). Presumably it can make this guarantee because the non-fast/least types are optional; if the system doesn't support types of that size *or* the types aren't 2's complement, it simply won't provide them.

Answer (score 2):

In eight-bit two's complement, the sign bit can be interpreted as having the place value -2<sup>8</sup>, which is of course -256.  This is in fact precisely how the C standard characterizes it.  Therefore, given an 8-bit value stored in a `uint8_t` that you want to reinterpret as a two's complement integer, this is an arithmetic way to do so:

```
uint8_t u8 = /* ... */;
int8_t  i8 = (u8 & 0x7f) - (u8 > 0x7f) * 0x100;
```

Note that all of the arithmetic is performed by first promoting the operands to (signed) `int`, so there is neither overflow (because the range of `int` is large enough for this) nor unsigned arithmetic wrap-around.  The arithmetic result is guaranteed to be in the range of `int8_t`, so there is no risk of overflow in the conversion of the result to that type, either.

You will note similarities between this computation and yours, but this one avoids the ternary operator by using the result of the relational expression `u8 > 0x7f` (either 0 or 1) directly in the arithmetic, thus avoiding any branching, and it dispenses with needless casts.  (Yours doesn't need the casts, either.)

Note also that if you run into some weird implementation that does not provide `int8_t` (because its `char`s are wider than 8 bits, or its `signed char`s do not use two's complement) then that arithmetic approach still works in the sense of computing the right value, and you can be certain of safely recording that value in an `int` or`short`.  Thus, the absolutely most portable way to extract the *value* of 8-bit two's complement interpretation of a uint8_t would be

```
uint8_t u8 = /* ... */;
int i8 = (u8 & 0x7f) - (u8 > 0x7f) * 0x100;
```

Alternatively, if you are willing to rely on `int8_t` to be a character type -- *i.e.* an alias for `char` or `signed char` -- then it is perfectly standard to do the job this way:

```
uint8_t u8 = /* ... */;
int8_t  i8 = *(int8_t *)&u8;
```

That one is even more likely to be optimized away by a compiler than is the `memcpy()` alternative presented in another answer, but unlike the `memcpy` alternative, this one formally has undefined behavior if `int8_t` turns out *not* to be a character type.  On the other hand, both this and the `memcpy()` approach depend on the implementation to provide type `int8_t`, and even more unlikely than an implementation not providing `int8_t` is that an implementation provides an `int8_t` that fails to be a character type.

Comment: "behavior if int8_t turns out not to be a character type" --> I see no possibility that this can be true.

Comment: @chux, it can be true if the implementation's `signed char` has 8-bit sign/magnitude or one's complement representation, but the implementation *also* provides an 8-bit two's complement data type as an extended signed integer type.

Answer (score -1):

Both `i8 = u8;` and `i8 = *(int8_t *)&u8;` will work on any system that actually exists and offers the `int8_t` type.

They rely on implementation-defined choices in both cases, but nobody would use an implementation that didn't make the obvious choices in these cases (in no small part because so much existing code also relies on those choices).  There's portability, and then there's mangling your code to cater for systems that will never exist.

Comment: Corner: `i8 = *(int8_t *)&u8` fails when `u8` is register.

Comment: @chux if declared `register` but there's no reason to do that these days (the optimizer can and will use registers even in the presence of this code)